# Android: Application is running slow after it's been migrated from old adt-bundle to latest android studio

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-studio, adt

Its been a year I was inactive with android development. Earlier I used to develop apps using adt-bundle eclipse. Recently I started working with Android studio.
I have migrated my application code by creating new files in android studio project and copied code, also made some changes in **manifest** and newly introduced **build.gradle** files.

---

First I got error,
**java.lang.OutOfMemoryError**

So I've added following in manifest file,
**android:largeHeap="true"**

This problem is resolved then.

---

Later I removed inherited class **ActionBarActivity** from activity classes, and inherited **AppCompatActivity**.
Also added following in **bundle.gradle**

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.3.0'
}
```

now I'm getting following errors,

```
I/Choreographer: Skipped 158 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
E/SpannableStringBuilder: SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
```

Is the problem arising due to following use of **findViewByID**

```
(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);
```

The main problem is, app is running very slow!!!

Comment: we need more details about 'running slow' what is the exact scenario. Build time? Startup time? clicking something time? Once you know this, add some logs and get back to us http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/TimingLogger.html

Comment: App is running very slow, means older version is responding real-time with touches, whereas current version is lagging in response with touch.

Comment: your app must be "doing something" there must be some code running somewhere that is slowing it down. We won't be able to answer this question with what you have just provided above

Comment: Your app is doing very intensive work. Maybe it is in a loop which is doing stuff with `SpannableStringBuilder`. If you want to do intensive work, do it in background by using Threads and Handlers.

Comment: @Blundell  thank you for showing interest. 
If  code is doing something then why one application built on old SDK is running efficiently and one built on new SDK is running slow, and both are same piece of code.

Comment: @shaggy007 I am facing the same issue. I migrated my app from Eclipse to Android studio and I didn't even change ActionBarActivity to AppCompatActivity. The UI is slightly better looking with new styles and stuff but when click on buttons there is a very noticeable lag which was not there before when build using eclipse.. I don't know where to look.

Comment: Running in same problem .App running slow when i migrated the project from eclipse to android studio. Have you sloved it @shaggy007

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you are having the same issue as mine. Mine was because my app has a configuration in AndroidManifest that says android:hardwareAccelerated="false"

This doesn't cause any lag issue in the old UI, but I am thinking that maybe with the new material design UI effects it introduces some lag unless we use hardware acceleration.

Try removing android:hardwareAccelerated="false" or set it to true to see if it still lags when responding to your touches. It solves mine.

Comment: The same, android:hardwareAccelerated="false" slowed down my app